# Skip iOS share-extension preparing step

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

For large media including images with size of ~10MB and videos of size ~200MB, iOS shows an preparing dialog and reduces the size of media.

Is there any way to skip this preparing step and get original media in share-extension for large files ?